# Issues related to WMS tile layer options (WMSTileLayerOptions not caching) using flutter_map_tile_caching: ^8.0.0

Tags: android, ios, flutter, fluttermap

I am using flutter_map_tile_cache lib to cache tile but I am not able to cache WMSTileLayerOptions layers please provide any solution

```
     TileLayer(
        wmsOptions: WMSTileLayerOptions(
          baseUrl: 'https://apps.xyz.com:8080/myserver/wms/?',
          layers: ['XYZLAYER:stateboundary],
          format: 'image/png',
          transparent: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.xyz',
        tileProvider: FMTC.instance('mapStore').getTileProvider(),
      ),
```

getting error like this:- FMTCBrowsingError: Failed to load the tile from the cache or the network because it was missing from the cache and a connection to the server could not be established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flutter libraries "flutter_map" and "cached_network_image" can fulfill our requirements.

We need to implement like this:

```
class CachedNetworkTileProvider extends TileProvider {
    @override
    ImageProvider getImage(TileCoordinates coordinates, TileLayer options) 
    {
     return CachedNetworkImageProvider(getTileUrl(coordinates, options));
    }
}
```

And

```
 TileLayer(wmsOptions: WMSTileLayerOptions(
          baseUrl: 'https://apps.example.com:8080/myserver/wms/?',
          layers: ['XYZLAYER:stateboundary'],
          format: 'image/png',
          transparent: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.xyz',
        tileProvider: CachedNetworkTileProvider(),
      ),
```